# Attempting to DNS resolve / relay an IPv6 address for a host

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, linux-networking, gentoo, hosts

I have a network switch doing IPv6 DNS relay to a Linux box (3.0.4-gentoo #7).

The packets (DNS request) are arriving fine at the Linux box.

Where I'm stuck now is how to resolve those, either by relaying again to a web DNS server (eg OpenDNS) or even resolving them locally and returning that back to the switch.

Various help files online talk about named.conf and /etc/hosts but many are just IPv4 and what I've tried from them doesn't seem to work.

Anyone got a 5-step guide to resolving IPv6 DNS requests (or relaying) on a Linux machine?

---EDIT---

I now have the named.conf and so on configured to some extent that the box is replying for DNS requests, but if I sniff the traffic, Wireshark shows it replying with response code Server failure.  Any theories on why?

Comment: DNS traffic really isn't any different over IPv4 versus IPv6 - there's no changes to the underlying protocol; `A` records can resolve if you're talking over IPv6 and `AAAA` records can resolve if you're talking over IPv4.  Can you clarify exactly what trouble you're having with having it resolve names over IPv6 communication?

Comment: updated with where I'm at.  I've got a zone created for .com addresses with the host in there.  In essence DNS isn't working, it's presumably not just IPv6, but in this case that's what I'm trying to set up - it' an IPv6 network.

Comment: Is the query for a record that actually exists?  Try the same query from the local system - sounds like you just have an issue with BIND's configuration.

Comment: You're not really clear exactly what type of queries are being sent to your linux box...